# $.post JQuery not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with form. After i click Dodaj button nothing happens.
I've putted alert dialog to see when it stops and it stops after

`$.post('dodaj_ztoner.php', post_data, function(response){`

I have made similar forms with similar code (names and number of items was different) and it worked

`alert('post');` is not displaying. so looks like problem is here `$.post('dodaj_ztoner.php', post_data, function(response){`

html code:

```
<body>
<div id="dialog" title="Błąd Wprowadzania!">    
  <p>Proszę uzupełnić podświetlone pola.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">


<fieldset id="contact_form">
<h2>Zużycie Tonera</h2>
<div id="zresult"></div>
<label for="id"><span>ID</span></label>
<input type="text" name="zid" id="zid" value="<?php
    $zapytanie = "select max(id) as id from zuzycie_toner";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    echo $wynik['id']+1;
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);
    ?>" disabled />


<label for="zdata"><span>Data wydania</span></label>
<input type="text" name="zdata" id="zdata"  />

<label for="ilwyd"><span>Ilość wydrukowanych</span> </label>
<input type="text" name="ilwyd" id="ilwyd"  />

<label for="drukarka"><span>Drukarka</span></label>  
 <select type="text" name="zdrukarka" id="zdrukarka" >
    <option selected="selected">Wybierz</option>
    <?php
    $zapytanie = "select nazwa from drukarki order by nazwa";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    echo "<option>$wynik[nazwa]</option>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);
    ?>
    </select>

<label for="toner"><span>Toner</span></label>  
 <select type="text" name="ztonery" id="ztonery" >
    <option selected="selected">Wybierz</option>
    <?php
    $zapytanie = "select nazwa from tonery order by nazwa";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    echo "<option>$wynik[nazwa]</option>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);
    ?>
    </select>




<label for="user"><span>Użytkownik</span> </label>
<select type="text" name="zuser" id="zuser" >
    <option selected="selected">Wybierz</option>
    <?php
    $zapytanie = "select nazwisko_imie as id from uzytkownicy order by nazwisko_imie";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    echo "<option>$wynik[id]</option>";
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);
    ?>
    </select>




<label><span>&nbsp;</span>
<button type="submit" class=submit_btn" id="zsubmit_btn">Dodaj</button>
</label>
```

JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var divObj = $('#dialog');
divObj.dialog({
autoOpen: false
}

);    
$( "#zdrukarka" ).selectmenu();
$( "#zuser" ).selectmenu();
$( "#ztonery" ).selectmenu();
$("#zdata").datepicker();
$( "button[type=submit]" )
  .button()
$("#zsubmit_btn").click(function() { 


    //Pobieramy dane
    var ztoner_id       = $('input[name=zid]').val(); 
    var ztoner_data       = $('input[name=zdata]').val(); 
    var ztoner_wydr      = $('input[name=ilwyd]').val(); 
    var ztoner_toner      = $('select[name=ztonery]').val();
    var ztoner_user      = $('select[name=zuser]').val();
    var ztoner_drukarka      = $('select[name=zdrukarka]').val();



   //Prosta walidacja (kolorujemy na czerwono pole jeśli jest puste
    var proceed = true;


 alert( '1');
    //wszystko w porządku idziemy dalej
    if(proceed) 
    {
        //Dane do wysłania
        post_data = {'ztonerID':ztoner_id, 'ztonerWydr':ztoner_wydr,     'ztonerData' :ztoner_data, 'ztonerToner' :ztoner_toner,
        'ztonerUser':ztoner_user, 'ztonerDrukarka':ztoner_drukarka};

        //Przesłanie danych poprzez AJAX
        $.post('dodaj_ztoner.php', post_data, function(response){  
 alert( 'post');
            //wczytanie danych zwrotnych JSON
            if(response.type == 'error')
            {
                output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
            }else{
                output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';


            }

            $("#zresult").hide().html(output).slideDown();
        }, 'json');

    } else divObj.dialog("open");   
});

//resetujemy kolorowanie po zaczęciu pisania

});
</script>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php

include './includes/html_elements.php';


//pokaz_zmienna($_SERVER);



$db_link = connect_db();

if(!$db_link)
{
$out='<p>Brak połączenia z bazą danych</p>';
print_page($out, 'Baza książek');
exit;
}

if($_POST)
{

 //Sprawdzamy czy jest to rządanie Ajax, jeśli nie..
 if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

//Kończymy skrypt wysyłając dane JSON
$output = json_encode(
 array(
 'type'=>'error', 
'text' => 'Rządanie musi przejść przez AJAX'
));

die($output);
 } 

//Sprawdzamy czy wszystkie pola zostały wysłane. kończymy skrypt jeśli nie    (tutaj dodawaj więcej pól, które są wymagane)
if(!isset($_POST["ztonerID"]))
{
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'POLA SĄ PUSTE!'));
die($output);
}

//Pobieramy dane z formularza
$ztoner_id = filter_var($_POST["ztonerID"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ztoner_data = filter_var($_POST["ztonerData"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ztoner_wydr = filter_var($_POST["ztonerWydr"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ztoner_drukarka = filter_var($_POST["ztonerDrukarka"],    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ztoner_toner = filter_var($_POST["ztonerToner"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ztoner_user = filter_var($_POST["ztonerUser"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);



//Dodatkowa validacja PHP (tylko dla pól wymaganych)

if(!is_numeric($ztoner_id)) //sprawdzamy czy telefon jest numeryczny
{
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Tylko liczby są dozwolone'));
die($output);
}

die($output);
    }


    $zapytanie = "select idd  from drukarki where nazwa = '$ztoner_drukarka'";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    $ztoner_drukarka = $wynik['idd'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);



    $zapytanie = "select idu  from uzytkownicy where nazwisko_imie = '$ztoner_user'";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    $ztoner_user = $wynik['idu'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);

    $zapytanie = "select idt  from tonery where nazwa = '$ztoner_toner'";
    $widok = mysql_query($zapytanie);
    while ($wynik = mysql_fetch_array($widok))
    {       
    $ztoner_toner = $wynik['idt'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($widok);




$insert = "Insert INTO zuzycie_toner Values ($ztoner_id, '$ztoner_data', $ztoner_wydr, $ztoner_drukarka, $ztoner_toner, '$ztoner_user')";

$wykonaj = mysql_query($insert);

if ($wykonaj)
{
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Dodano '.$drukarki_nazwa.' do tabeli'));
 die($output);
 }else{
$output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Dodawanie nie powiodło się '.$insert));
die($output);
 }

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Check in your console if there is any error and post it

Comment: Do what @Gersey told and did you know data whats the value returned from variabel `response` from you $.post?

Comment: You should check your php script, you have one `}` too many so you get a fatal parse error.

Comment: I've checked console and there was no errors. @jeroen thanks for `}`

Answer (score 1):

Your page doesn't conatains any form tag, so simple use

`<button class=submit_btn" id="zsubmit_btn">Dodaj</button>`  instead of input type = submit

This will Work!!!!